# Centering an image in a div

Tags: css, xhtml, centering

I had just gotten through setting up a div inside a div and I wanted a graphic in the inner div which I managed to do and centre so I gave myself a big pat on the back for atleast trying and getting that far without having to go back to using dream weaver.

Then I tried to create a class for a div that I could use to produce three columns to put text and images in.  When I couldn't get that to work I went back to using tables because div's can be such a bitch and then I never know if the div's are going to display correctly in every browser as tables seem to be more stable.

Here is a link to what I have done so far so you get the picture [michael.sydney](http://michael.sydney).

I have a link to how it was looking without the table with a centered graphic and then an example of how it looks now.

Comment: Centering a div inside a div is a difficult but much discussed problem.  Lots of sites give explanations.  Try this page: http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/

Comment: If horizontal centering is not what you want, try to be a bit mor clear in your question.

Comment: Why would you not mark the answer that solved your problem? This way other SO users will not immediately find that this has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I tried adding

```
#boxInner {
   text-align: center;
}
```

And it worked for your page